# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException of ChromeDriver supports Chrome 110 version is 112.0.5615.138

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-app

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 110
Current browser version is 112.0.5615.138 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:

Tried to install and uninstall chrome and driver . Still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and the use the chrome driver version compatible with "112.0.5615.138 " of chrome installed in your machine
You can download it from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Better alternative would be to use Webdrivermanager if you are using java, it simplifies the process of setting up WebDriver by downloading the appropriate driver binary, based on the user's operating system and the version of the browser you are using

just add this code before driver initilisation

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

[Webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)